# Mirth -> HL7 into XML conversion Ques

Tags: mirth, hl7-v2

I'm new to the Mirth Connect When I tried to convert HL7 into XML I 'm struggling.Suppose my HL7 messages have repeat segments like ORC in ORM Messages how to iterate that.
below is my code:

```
tmp['Messages']['orderList']['order'][count]['provider']=msg['ORC'][count]['ORC.10']['ORC.10.1'].toString();
```

but it is throwing an error:

```
`TypeError: Cannot read property "provider"` from undefined.
```

please help me to proceed further.

Comment: There is a code template on the right side of any transformer script to iterate over segments. Have you tried that?

Comment: yes Shamli I have tried but it is not working

Answer (score 1):

It's failing because your `count` is higher than the number of elements returned by `tmp['Messages']['orderList']['order']`, so it is returning undefined. The short answer is that you need to add another `order` node to `tmp['Messages']['orderList']` before you can access it. It's hard to say how best to do that without seeing more of your code, requirements, outbound template, etc... Most frequently I build the node first, and then use appendChild to add it.

A simple example would be:

```
var tmp = <xml>
    <Messages>
        <orderList />
    </Messages>
</xml>;

var prov = 12345;
var nextOrder = <order>
    <provider>{prov}</provider>
</order>;

tmp.Messages.orderList.appendChild(nextOrder);
```

After which, `tmp` will look like:

```
<xml>
    <Messages>
        <orderList>
            <order>
                <provider>12345</provider>
            </order>
        </orderList>
    </Messages>
</xml>
```

The technology you are using to work with xml is called e4x, and it's running on the Mozilla Rhino Javascript engine. Here are a couple resources that might help you.

https://web.archive.org/web/20181120184304/https://wso2.com/project/mashup/0.2/docs/e4xquickstart.html

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Archive/Web/E4X/Processing_XML_with_E4X